# Add Migration for Existing Table with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am in a situation where we have been using (code first) EF migrations against a database that is used as the backing store for two applications. Over the past year or so, we have successfully made DB changes via migrations.

However, at some point a few tables seem to have been manually added and we are now experiencing FK reference errors when we try to delete.

I have attempted the obvious, with the obvious result:  Adding the models and generating a migration is going to attempt to recreate the tables in the database.

Is there a strategy to add these new tables to our data model and get our migrations up to date?

Comment: You mean, you have an existing database, you want to be able to run migrations on it, you don't have that db as an EF context and you want to use code first to manage that DB. Is that correct?

Comment: Never tried this, but maybe you can use migrations to add the same tables to a copy of the database (without the tables) and then copy the migrations table to the original database.

Comment: You could comment out the code that creates the existing objects to get your model back in sync. A safer alternative is to just [reset your migrations](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/jan/13/resetting-entity-framework-migrations-to-a-clean-slate).